# Convert errors (notices/warnings) into exceptions?

Tags: php

I already set my error handler:

```
set_error_handler (function($errno, $errstr, $errfile,  $errline, array $errcontext) {
  $s = date('Ymd_His');
  switch ($errno)
  {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
      $s.= '_E_';
      break;
    case E_USER_WARNING:
      $s.= '_W_';
      break;
    case E_USER_NOTICE:
      $s.= '_N_';
      break;
    default:
      $s.= '_U_';
      break;
    }
    file_put_contents (APP_PATH_CACHE.'/log'.$s.'_'.rand(1,99999).'.html', print_r(get_defined_vars(), true));
}, E_ALL);
```

but can it be turn into an exception? So that I could see the flow.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Duplicated from question [10520390](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520390/stop-script-execution-upon-notice-warning)? Anyway, upvoting...

Comment: well, to me it wasnt straightforward. If I throw just an exception, the backtrace will lead into the error handler, not the source of it. Similar problem with "fatal errors" in "shutdown"

Comment: @JohnSmith the backtrace does cross the error handler location indeed, but it doesn't stop there, it continues to the line where the error was generated, see https://3v4l.org/CpsPS , they all mention line 13, where the error was generated. (since at least php 5.1, but probably earlier,  but cba testing because ErrorException was introduced in 5.1)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes.
this is exactly why the ErrorException was created. see http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

for PHP>=8.1.0:

```php
function exception_error_handler(int $errno, string $errstr, string $errfile = null, int $errline) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }
    throw new \ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler(exception_error_handler(...));
```

for PHP>=7.0.0:

```php
function exception_error_handler(int $errno, string $errstr, string $errfile = null, int $errline) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }
    throw new \ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler(__NAMESPACE__ . "\\exception_error_handler");
```

for PHP>=5.3.0:

```php
<?php
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile = null, $errline) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }
    throw new \ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler(__NAMESPACE__ . "\\exception_error_handler");
```

for PHP>=5.1.0:

```php
<?php
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile = null, $errline) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be simply done. Best way is to create your own class that extends from \Exception and in your error_handler() throw object of this new class.

You can do it also in simple way after

`file_put_contents (APP_PATH_CACHE.'/log'.$s.'_'.rand(1,99999).'.html', print_r(get_defined_vars(), true));`

add

`throw new Exception($errst, $errno);` where first param is message and second is error number